Looking for an animated TV short featuring a conqueror, a blue flower, and a white humanoid
In the late 1980s or early 1990s, I recall watching a sci-fi color animated TV short in the Moebius style. It was in English and about a rainforest (I deduce that the story takes place in South America in the centuries of the conquest given what follows) where a young explorer, dressed like a conqueror, searching for the fabled land known as El Dorado, comes across a blue withered flower. The explorer, then, recalls a legend told to him by natives about a magical blue flower that blooms for one single day and before dying shows the way to El Dorado to everyone who sees it before withering. The explorer is filled with anguish. Then, from behind some bushes, a small, pure white skinny humanoid being (like a Pillsbury Doughboy on a crash diet without the scarf and the chef's hat) approached the explorer and telepathically tells him that, if he wants to know the path to the gold city, he must return to the same location in 50 years to see the flower bloom again. The white figure disappears.
Fifty years later, the explorer, now elderly, returns to the site where he had discovered the faded flower and finds the blooming blue flower. The white humanoid reappears precisely as before, telepathically asking the explorer whether he still wants to find El Dorado. The old man said, "No. I am too old now for that". "Why did you come back, then?" asked the white being. The explorer answered: "To capture you". The old man catches the white being using an earthen jar which covers with banana leaves, and he leaves. Does this sound familiar to you?

yes, it does ..
